# Laravel how to seed in a table with foreign key?

Tags: laravel, database, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make the 2 most simple tables work with a foreign key referring to the 'parent' table, but I just can't seem to get it to work.
This is my first table (users):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('toegewezen');
    });
}
```

This is my second table (bestellingen):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bestellingen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('bestel_id');
        $table->string("drank");
        $table->string("categorie");
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); // also tried nullable()
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer("aantal");
        $table->string("status");
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

When I migrate this everything looks fine, it's just when I try to actually seed the data into the tables it fails and gives me the following error code: `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('ipmedth'.'bestellingen', CONSTRAINT 'bestellingen_user_id_foreign' FOREIGN KEY ('user_id') REFERENCES 'users' ('id')) (SQL: insert into 'bestellingen' ('drank', 'categorie', 'user_id', 'aantal', 'status') values (Cola, Frisdrank, 1, 1, Besteld))`.
I've tried looking up the error but I can't seem to find anything that can help me. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. These are my seeders:

Users table seeder:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => 'Pieter',
    'toegewezen' => 'Nee'
]);
```

Bestellingen table seeder:

```
DB::table('bestellingen')->insert([
    'drank' => 'Cola',
    'categorie' => 'Frisdrank',
    'user_id' => 1, // also tried with '1' and without entire line
    'aantal' => 1,
    'status' => "Besteld",
]);
```

Comment: Make sure they are run in the correct order. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72551222/edit) and include your `DatabaseSeeder.php` file?

Comment: Or, a different approach: `foreach(DB::table('users')->get() as $user) { DB::table('bestellingen')->insert(['user_id' => $user->id, ...]); }` (replacing `...` with the other columns to populate)

Comment: Oh my god that was actually the answer, had to change around the order... Thanks @TimLewis !!!

Comment: Wonderful! I figured you might be running into an issue if you used Alphabetical sorting on the Seeder class names (bestellingen comes before users after all). But yes, switch them around and `'user_id' => 1` would work, or the "safer" `foreach()` approach. Cheers! 

Comment: Thing is that I didn't add that line of code so never even took a look at it as it seemed logical to me that it would be the other way around.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Write foreign key like this"

$table->foreignIdFor(User::class, 'userId');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).